# Pause execution of javascript code until response received from api call

Tags: javascript, async-await

I need to pause the execution of code until the response is received from the API call function `getUserViews()`. I tried using `async`/`await` but its not working.

```js
async getUser() {
  await this.rcService.getUserViews().toPromise().then(data => {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      console.log('default user ===');
      console.log(data);

      CurrentUser.user.userName = data[0].UserName;
      CurrentUser.user.userId = data[0].UserID;
      CurrentUser.user.email = data[0].UserEmailID;
      CurrentUser.user.userType = data[0].UserType;
      CurrentUser.user.rolesAndLayouts = data[0].opexAccountLayout;
      this.updateUserPreferences(CurrentUser.user.userType);
      this.updateUserMenu();
    } else {
      console.log('no user found with given details');
      this.router.navigate(['401']);
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('error in fetcing user');
    console.log(error);
    this.router.navigate(['401']);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working? What is happening and what should be happening instead?

Comment: you are missing the `function` keyword (`async function getUser() { ... }`)

Comment: @secan it's probably a method. I guess based on the usage of `this`.